# How to check text box length and check for duplicates at the same time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a problem trying to figure this out I want to check for duplicates and check if the length is lesser or equal to 3 in my username text box. After both returns valid I enable enable the next text box.

HTML:

```
<label for="uName" style="margin-left: 8px;">User Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="uName" name="uName" style="margin-left: 7px;" onkeyup="checkEmpty();checkUname();" disabled><br><br>
<label for="pWord1" style="margin-left: 8px;" >Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="pWord1" name="pWord1" style="margin-left: 17px;" onkeyup="checkLength();checkUname();" disabled>
```

As you can see I'm using 2 key up events which I know part of the problem so below is both of the events.

JavaScritp: (This check's if the username lesser or equal to 3)

```
function checkEmpty() {
    var msg = document.getElementById('msg'),
        uName = document.getElementById('uName'),
        pass1 = document.getElementById("pWord1");

    if ($("#uName").is(':focus')){//TODO combine check uname function with this one
            if (uName.value.length <= 3){
                msg.innerHTML = "User name is too short";
                pass1.disabled = true;
            }else{
                msg.innerHTML = "";
                pass1.disabled = false;
            }
    }
```

JavaScript: (This part get the text box value and checks it form the database)

```
function checkUname() {

    var uName = document.getElementById("uName").value,
        pass1 = document.getElementById("pWord1");

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            if (xmlhttp.responseText === "1"){
                document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="Username taken";
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST","../Functions/matchUname.php?uName="+uName,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

include_once("../iConnect/handShake.php");

if (isset($_REQUEST["uName"])){

    $getUname = "SELECT uName FROM userlogin WHERE uName = :uName";
    $getUnameQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($getUname);
    $getUnameQuery -> bindParam(':uName', $_REQUEST["uName"]);
    $getUnameQuery -> execute();

    if ($row = $getUnameQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "1";
    }else{
        echo "2";
    }

}
```

I hope I made my self clear so please if any one can just guide me towards the light would be a grate help.

**EDIT:** Below is my problem in detail.

There's no error both are working problem is I need the pass1 text box to be in disabled mode until both functions finish I did try to pass the pass1.dissabled = false`through the`checUname()` function but as soon as I hit a key pass1 text box get enabled.

**UPDATE:** Managed to get it working as I intended it to work so the JavaScript code is blow hope it help's some one else in future.

```
if ($("#uName").is(':focus')){
 if (uName.value.length <= 3){
   msg.innerHTML = "User name is too short";
   pass1.disabled = true;
 }else{
     if(uName.value.length > 0){
        checkUname();
     }
 }}

function checkUname() {

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                if (xmlhttp.responseText === "1"){
                    msg.innerHTML="Username taken";
                    pass1.disabled = true;
                }else{
                    msg.innerHTML = "";
                    pass1.disabled = false;
                }
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST","../Functions/matchUname.php?uName="+uName.value,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? What's happening? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Could you please tell what errors are you getting exactly?

Comment: There's no error both are working problem is I need the pass1 text box to be in disabled mode until both functions finish I did try to pass the `pass1.dissabled = false` through the `checUname()` function but as soon as I hit a key pass1 text box get enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you:

```
function checkUname(uName) {

if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        if (xmlhttp.responseText === "1"){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST","../Functions/matchUname.php?uName="+uName,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Then call it in:

```
if ($("#uName").is(':focus')){//TODO combine check uname function with this one
        if (uName.value.length <= 3){
            msg.innerHTML = "User name is too short";
            pass1.disabled = true;
        }else{
           if(checkUname(uName.value) {
               msg.innerHTML = "User name already in use";
               pass1.disabled = true;
           } else {
               msg.innerHTML = "";
               pass1.disabled = false;
           }
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the way I wanted do this but messed up while doing I will try this and let you know.

Comment: I tried it, the code skips the `if(cehckUname(uName.value)` part and jumps straight to the else part.

Comment: Is this how you spelt it in your code **if(cehckUname(uName.value)** if so it should be **if(checkUname(uName.value)**

Comment: Comment was a typo I made while I was typing code is the same as your's

Comment: Made a minor tweak to the checkUname function, this shouldn't make a much difference, but give it a try

Comment: Nope it didn't work but based on your input I made the above mentioned code and it works.